# Join of table subset columns retuns a object intead of data on sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Trying do some SQLAlchemy voodoo:

- Database has 2 tables that are reflected
- Base declaration creating subsetting the column structure
- Make a join query
- Retrieve the result

The code goes as follows:

```
db_tables  = ["descriptor","desc_attribute"]
db_engine = create_engine(<REMOVED>, echo = True)
db_metadata = MetaData()
db_metadata.reflect(bind=db_engine, only=db_tables)
Session = sessionmaker(db_engine)  
session = Session()

DescriptorTable = db_metadata.tables[db_tables[0]]
AttributeTable = db_metadata.tables[db_tables[1]]

Base = declarative_base()

class DescriptorTable2(Base):
    __table__ = DescriptorTable
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'include_properties' :[
            DescriptorTable.c.descriptor_id,#PK
            DescriptorTable.c.desc_attribute_id, #FK
            DescriptorTable.c.desc_attribute_standard_id],

}

class AttributeTable2(Base):
    __table__ = AttributeTable
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'include_properties' :[
            AttributeTable.c.desc_attribute_id, #PK
            AttributeTable.c.dataset_id,
            AttributeTable.c.source_attribute_description,
            AttributeTable.c.source_attribute_unit,
            ]

}
```

The section above generates 2 new derived tables that have columns as subset

Then doing a join for a specific record:

```
result = session.query(DescriptorTable2,AttributeTable2).
          join(AttributeTable2).filter(DescriptorTable2.descriptor_id == 20662).all()
```

It generated the following SQL:

```
SELECT descriptor.descriptor_id AS descriptor_descriptor_id, descriptor.desc_attribute_id AS descriptor_desc_attribute_id, descriptor.desc_attribute_standard_id AS descriptor_desc_attribute_standard_id, desc_attribute.desc_attribute_id AS desc_attribute_desc_attribute_id, desc_attribute.dataset_id AS desc_attribute_dataset_id, desc_attribute.source_attribute_description AS desc_attribute_source_attribute_description, desc_attribute.source_attribute_unit AS desc_attribute_source_attribute_unit 
FROM descriptor JOIN desc_attribute ON desc_attribute.desc_attribute_id = descriptor.desc_attribute_id 
WHERE descriptor.descriptor_id = %(descriptor_id_1)s
```

The SQL looks correct but the return result object is something like:

```
(<__main__.DescriptorTable2 object at 0x7ff0fb7d8780>, <__main__.AttributeTable2 object at 0x7ff0fb7d8828>)
```

Doing object introspection I can't see any results or content

BUT if I declare the columns on the join:

```
result = session.query(DescriptorTable2.desc_attribute_standard_id,
                       AttributeTable2.dataset_id,
                       AttributeTable2.source_attribute_description,
                       AttributeTable2.source_attribute_unit,
                       ).join(AttributeTable2).filter(DescriptorTable2.descriptor_id == 20662).all()
```

The result has the proper structure:

```
('Spectral near infra red reflectance (NIR)', 'WD-ISIS-NIR', 'Spectral near infra red (NIR) for 205 wavelengths', 'nm')
```

Declaring the columns on the JOIN is agains my objective of having a new declared table and use a very simple JOIN statement.

So, what is wrong with this approach and could it make it work (to much overthinking?)

Comment: Nothing's wrong, the result is a 2-tuple of model instances.

Comment: You are correct, the model then constains the result, was just expecting that result to be an easy to operate object

Comment: It is. The results allow accessing the entities by their position or name. For example `result[0].DescriptorTable2`.

Answer (score 0):

Better introspection to the object revealed the

```
result[0][0].desc_attribute_standard_id
'Spectral near infra red reflectance (NIR)'
```

First item is `DescriptorTable2` and contains the attributes from that table